# Sending audio message with Twilio Conversations

Tags: twilio, twilio-conversations

I am trying to send audio message with twillio conversations. According to the documentation I should send a contentType and a media of type string or Buffer. The Buffer constructor is missing in JS so I used the following method to create a buffer: Here is my send message request (I have tried sending different content types. And even audio in base64. Nothing worked.):

```
   function toBuffer(ab: any) {
     const buf = Buffer.alloc(ab.byteLength)
     const view = new Uint8Array(ab)
     for (let i = 0; i < buf.length; i += 1) {
       buf[i] = view[i]
    }
    return buf
   }
   const arrayBuffer = await new FileReader().readAsArrayBuffer(new Blob([message.audio]))
   chats[chat].conversation?.sendMessage({
        contentType: 'audio/wav',
        media: toBuffer(arrayBuffer)
      }, {
        messageId: uuidv4(),
        ...attributes
      })
```

I request the audio URL with the function provided by twillio conversations:

```
message.media.getContentTemporaryUrl()
```

It returns a URL which doe not contain a valid audio file and cannot be played. Please help me to find the propper way of send a valid audo message and being able to play it.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though you are working with the client side JS library, so using Node features like Buffers won't work.

The [media documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/media-support-conversations#javascript) for the JS SDK says:

> For JavaScript, you can provide the following as the source for the new media message sent by a Chat-based Conversation Participant:
>
> - A new FormData object containing file information: filename, content-type, size, and all FormData-required information

So you could do it like:

```js
const file = document.getElementById("#formInputFile").files[0];
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', file]);
formData.append('contentType', 'audio/wav')'

chats[chat].conversation?.sendMessage(formData);
```